# Can there be discrepancies between ORC and OBR common elements in HL7 ORU messages?

Tags: hl7, hl7-v2

Does anyone know whether it is common to see values in the OBR segment not match the values from similar concepts in the ORC segment for laboratory diagnostic result HL7 ORU messages?

For example:

ORC.7.6 - Priority
OBR.27.6 - Priority

Can it be possible that the ORC shows "routine", but one of the OBR values underneath that shows "stat" for one of a few tests ordered?  (So that parsing logic needs to look at OBR first, OCR second to be accurate?)

Similarly, can this same phenomenon happen with the ordering provider?
ORC.12 - Ordering Provider
OBR.16 - Ordering Provider

For example, if a physician orders a Hep B test that comes back as positive, and the lab's middleware has rules that order a reflux test for Surface B antigen or something else automatically, then the original ordering physician isn't who technically placed the reflux order, but the middleware rule.  How is this usually expressed between the ORC.12 and OBR.16 segments corresponding to the ordering provider?

(Don't think it's relevant, but we're reading HL7 v2.5.1 ORU messages)

Comment: FYI, this document mentions your ORC-12 situation.  https://www.cdc.gov/ehrmeaningfuluse/docs/elr251_clarification_ehr_tech_cert-20120716.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ORC` is Common Order Segment. The `OBR` is Observation Request Segment.

The data in those respective segments is related to that specific segment. It may or may not be same.

Comment: Thanks Amit, that's what I suspected, I appreciate your help to confirm that for me.  I'll end up implementing something to test for the OBR attribute first and trust that first, and use the ORC value as a fallback.